# Does Doctrine2 apply filters to delete statements

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine filters and recently noticed that filters are not applied to delete statements. I have tried to dig through documentation and google, but mystery stays unsolved.

For example I have filter which connects user to company so every select query like:

```
$userRepo->find(12);
```

and is modified from

> SELECT .... FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = 12

into

> SELECT .... FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = 12 AND (t0.company_id = '6')

cool, that is what I need.

What bothers me is that delete statements seems to be untouched. Does anyone know if it is default doctrine architecture or my configuration is wrong?

The filter

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;

class CompanyAware extends SQLFilter
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    protected $reader;

    /**
     * @param ClassMetaData $targetEntity
     * @param string $targetTableAlias
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        $query = '';
        $ann = 'Mrok\\PortalBundle\\Annotation\\CompanyAware';
        $isAware = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation($targetEntity->getReflectionClass(), $ann);

        if ($isAware) {
            $id = $this->getParameter('id');
            $query = sprintf('%s.company_id = %s', $targetTableAlias, $id);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function setAnnotationReader(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your sql filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doctrine Repositories doesn't have a delete(id) or deleteBy(criteria) as a built-in, I assume you are referring to either $em->remove($entity); or DQL. Looking at the code (see below) neither Remove or cascade remove apply filters before executing the SQL. The documentation indicates that filters should be applied to DQL.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

```
/**
 * Deletes a managed entity.
 *
 * The entity to delete must be managed and have a persistent identifier.
 * The deletion happens instantaneously.
 *
 * Subclasses may override this method to customize the semantics of entity deletion.
 *
 * @param object $entity The entity to delete.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function delete($entity)
{
    $class      = $this->class;
    $em         = $this->em;

    $identifier = $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityIdentifier($entity);
    $tableName  = $this->quoteStrategy->getTableName($class, $this->platform);
    $idColumns  = $this->quoteStrategy->getIdentifierColumnNames($class, $this->platform);
    $id         = array_combine($idColumns, $identifier);
    $types      = array_map(function ($identifier) use ($class, $em) {

        if (isset($class->fieldMappings[$identifier])) {
            return $class->fieldMappings[$identifier]['type'];
        }

        $targetMapping = $em->getClassMetadata($class->associationMappings[$identifier]['targetEntity']);

        if (isset($targetMapping->fieldMappings[$targetMapping->identifier[0]])) {
            return $targetMapping->fieldMappings[$targetMapping->identifier[0]]['type'];
        }

        if (isset($targetMapping->associationMappings[$targetMapping->identifier[0]])) {
            return $targetMapping->associationMappings[$targetMapping->identifier[0]]['type'];
        }

        throw ORMException::unrecognizedField($targetMapping->identifier[0]);

    }, $class->identifier);

    $this->deleteJoinTableRecords($identifier);
    $this->conn->delete($tableName, $id, $types);
}

/**
 * @todo Add check for platform if it supports foreign keys/cascading.
 *
 * @param array $identifier
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function deleteJoinTableRecords($identifier)
{
    foreach ($this->class->associationMappings as $mapping) {
        if ($mapping['type'] !== ClassMetadata::MANY_TO_MANY) {
            continue;
        }

        // @Todo this only covers scenarios with no inheritance or of the same level. Is there something
        // like self-referential relationship between different levels of an inheritance hierarchy? I hope not!
        $selfReferential = ($mapping['targetEntity'] == $mapping['sourceEntity']);
        $class           = $this->class;
        $association     = $mapping;
        $otherColumns    = array();
        $otherKeys       = array();
        $keys            = array();

        if ( ! $mapping['isOwningSide']) {
            $class       = $this->em->getClassMetadata($mapping['targetEntity']);
            $association = $class->associationMappings[$mapping['mappedBy']];
        }

        $joinColumns = $mapping['isOwningSide']
            ? $association['joinTable']['joinColumns']
            : $association['joinTable']['inverseJoinColumns'];


        if ($selfReferential) {
            $otherColumns = (! $mapping['isOwningSide'])
                ? $association['joinTable']['joinColumns']
                : $association['joinTable']['inverseJoinColumns'];
        }

        foreach ($joinColumns as $joinColumn) {
            $keys[] = $this->quoteStrategy->getJoinColumnName($joinColumn, $class, $this->platform);
        }

        foreach ($otherColumns as $joinColumn) {
            $otherKeys[] = $this->quoteStrategy->getJoinColumnName($joinColumn, $class, $this->platform);
        }

        if (isset($mapping['isOnDeleteCascade'])) {
            continue;
        }

        $joinTableName = $this->quoteStrategy->getJoinTableName($association, $this->class, $this->platform);

        $this->conn->delete($joinTableName, array_combine($keys, $identifier));

        if ($selfReferential) {
            $this->conn->delete($joinTableName, array_combine($otherKeys, $identifier));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I assume you are referring to either $em->remove($entity);" - yes I do