# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 Respository - Set Where Condition for All Methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When working with a repository, all queries to the Foo Entity require the same condition to be set.  What I plan to do is set an account_id property on the repository and use this with any find methods, how ever is this the right way to do this?

```
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository {

public function setAccountId($account_id) {
    $this->account_id = $account_id;
}

public function findOneBy(array $criteria, mixed $orderBy = null)
{
    $criteria += array('account'=>$this->account_id);
    return parent::findOneBy($criteria, $orderBy);
}

}
```

Or is it better to just update every find method and set the criteria when calling it:

```
getRepository('Foo')->findOneBy(array('id'=>1,'account_id'=>2));
```

The repository also contains custom methods for searching Foo, these would also have to include the account_id.

```
function search($query=null, $current_page = 1, $page_size = 20) {
...
        $qb->andWhere('f.account = :account_id')
            ->setParameter('account_id',$this->account_id);
```

**Using Doctrine Filters**

> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

This seems like it will allow me to manipulate the query when selecting from the Foo Entity.  But what about if I am selecting from Bar which has a relationship to Foo, is it possible to add a join when it does not exist using filters?

For example:

```
SELECT FROM Bar
```

Should become:

```
SELECT FROM BAR JOIN Foo WHERE Foo.account_id=x
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Doctrine Filters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429599/does-doctrine2-apply-filters-to-delete-statements) could be useful also

Comment: Could filters be added to include joins? (question updated with details).

Comment: i don't kwon (i don't experiment this features directly) but i hope/seem possible if the `BAR` entity implements the interface (doc example) or with custom annotation (SO question). Hope this help. Let me know!

Comment: Just found a feature request for this feature and it was rejected http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2404 I guess my best option is to update every query manually. Is having something like `setAccountId() ` on a repository good practice?

Comment: excuse me for the wrong suggestion...

Comment: No offense was meant, I've learnt something new about Doctrine and Filters. So I am happy in that respect, just not so much about the code mess I might need to introduce.